# How to implement a multi form 'wizard' using forms

Tags: python, django

I'm *not* using django-formtools, just built in forms.

I'm struggling to understand the correct flow to construct such a view.

I was trying to chain my logic like so

```
def step_one(request, ...):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = step_one_form(data=request.POST)
    else:
        form = step_one_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        foo = request.POST.get('foo')
        return step_two(request,foo)
    return render(request, 'wizard.html', context={'form',form})

def step_two(request, ...)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = step_two_form(data=request.POST)
    else:
        form = step_two_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        foo = request.POST.get('foo')
        bar = request.POST.get('bar')
        return step_three(request, foo, bar)
   return render(request, 'wizard.html', context={'form',form}

def get_view(request):
    return step_one(request)
```

Edit:  I realized that I can past data=request.POST to my form constructor, and that kind of works, but because step_two etc are always POST the form always shows "this field is required" errors on the first rendering.

What is the preferred technique to not render the error on first load?  Do you have to use a hidden field or something?

Comment: What framework are you using? Flask? Django?

Comment: Django, sorry did not tag it in the question.  I'm quite new with django, so i make obvious mistakes sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the proper thing to do here is, but my solution was a hidden element on each step of the wizard, and checking the value of that input to see if it was posted from the same step in the wizard.